# qiskit - MCMT - base gate acting on only one qubit

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

I want to reduce the depth of a [ucrz](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.ucrz.html) gate acting on multiple qubits with ancilla qubits in qiskit. One way to do this could be the [mcmt](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.MCMT.html) implementation with `method='v-chain'`. However, it seems that `mcmt` is incompatible with base gates acting on multiple qubits. How can I reduce the circuit depth with ancillas?

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.extensions.quantum_initializer.ucrz import UCRZGate
import numpy as np

nqbits=3 # the number of qubits
qr = QuantumRegister(nqbits) #initialize register
QM = QuantumCircuit(qr) #initialize circuits
ang_li=list([np.pi,np.pi,-np.pi,np.pi])# list of angles
QM.ucrz(ang_li,q_controls=[qr[1],qr[2]],q_target=[qr[0]])#apply the gate
on the first register
display(QM.draw())#This is the full circuit
display(QM.decompose().decompose().decompose().draw()) #This is the decomposed circuit whose depth I wanna reduce with ancillas

qr2 = QuantumRegister(2*nqbits-1) #initialize the second register
ancilla = QuantumCircuit(qr2) #initialize the second circuit 
ancilla.mcmt(UCRZGate(ang_li),[1,2],0,[4,5], mode='v-chain') #try to apply the same gate with 'vchain'+ ancilas. it gives an error!! Seens mcmt is incompatible with base gates acting on multiple qubits
display(ancilla.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().draw())
print(ancilla.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().count_ops())
print(ancilla.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().depth())
```

Comment: Follow up question regarding the MCMT function. Can it be used to make a controlled-A gate where A is an arbitrary unitary having 1 or more targets?